# How do I move the sentence below the username section?

Tags: html, css, layout

So I have this problem where the span is covering the whole space of the div, is there some way to not make it do that? Or are there alternatives? I need the other text to move down but I'm stuck and I don't know what to do... Please help

```css
.post-area {
  margin-left: 5rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.twit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.name {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--text-secondary);
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.username {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  color: var(--text-primary);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.twit-post {
  display: inline-block;
}

.post-user {
  display: flex;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.twit-post {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-area">
  <div class="twit">
    <img class="userpfp post-user" src="images/user_pfp.jpg" />
    <span class="name">Suisei 
    <i class="username"> @suisei_comet</i>
    </span>
    <br />
    <p class="twit-post">Oh I just made something new!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[The picture shows that its covering the whole div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eGIn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```css
.post-area {
  margin-left: 5rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.twit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.name {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--text-secondary);
  font-weight: normal;
  height: auto;
}

.username {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  color: var(--text-primary);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.twit-post {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.post-user {
  display: flex;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-area">
  <div class="twit">
    <img class="userpfp post-user" src="images/user_pfp.jpg" />
    <div class="twit-post">
      <span class="name">Suisei <i class="username"> @suisei_comet </i></span>
      <p>Oh I just made something new!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```